# Difference between ubuntu desktop and ubuntu desktop usb

Tags: linux, installation, ubuntu-12.04

I downloaded mini iso **Ubuntu 12.04 "Precise Pangolin" Minimal CD** from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

I try to install on 2 GB free space. I prefer ubuntu desktop but i have no idea what is the different between **Ubuntu desktop** and **Ubuntu desktop USB** ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you aren't using Ubuntu Server, but I suspect the issue is the same. It would seem this is a bug from Ubuntu 11.10. You can also see a related question from askbubuntu.com, which I have quoted below.

> a bug that snuck into the seeds that were used to build ISO's for Ubuntu 11.10, presumably fairly late, as it was not caught in the fairly comprehensive beta ISO testing.  [Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66137/what-is-ubuntu-desktop-usb-in-tasksel)

[Source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tasksel/+bug/869796)

Comment: So, Ubuntu desktop and Ubuntu desktop USB is the same thing?

Comment: So go with Ubuntu Desktop and ignore Ubuntu Desktop USB.

Comment: also present on my Ubuntu Server 14.04.02 LTS

Comment: also present in Ubuntu 17.10